# Create excel file and save all voltage results into it using Python

Tags: python, excel

I want to make a Python code that calculates the voltage with a series of currents given and fixed resistor value.
V = IR....R is 5 ohm. Current list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. Python will create an Excel file and all voltage results will be added and saved in Excel.

Comment: I would suggest: use a `for` loop to loop through each element in the list of current value, then calculate the voltage by `V=I*R`, then 1) store it to a list and write to an Excel file (csv is the simplest), or 2) open the Excel file before the `for` loop and write to that file after the calculation of each voltage value. Anyway, you should provide more information, and the progress you have done so far. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP wants a simple code, so I will do it. Note that you might need to change the code to meet your need.

```py
current = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # Current list
r = 5 # R = 5 ohm
voltage = [] # A "place holder" list for holding the voltage values

# A for loop to loop through each value in the list

for i in current:
    voltage.append(i*r) # Calculate the voltage by V = I*R, then append that value to the place holder list

# Open a file and write to it
# In this example we will write to the CSV format
# In CSV, each value is separated by a comma (",")

f = open("output.csv", "w")

f.write("Current,Voltage\n") # Header of two columns

# Write each pair of current and voltage to the file
for i in range(0, len(current)):
    f.write(str(current[i]) + "," + str(voltage[i]) + "\n")

f.close() # Close the file
```

Or a more simple version:

```py
current = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # Current list
r = 5 # R = 5 ohm

# Open a file and write to it
# In this example we will write to the CSV format
# In CSV, each value is separated by a comma (",")

f = open("output.csv", "w")

f.write("Current,Voltage\n") # Header of two columns

# A for loop to loop through each value in the list

for i in current:
    f.write(str(i) + "," + str(i*r) + "\n") # Calculate the voltage by V = I*R, then write to file

f.close() # Close the file
```

After that, you can open your file in Excel and view the result.

If you want the `xlsx` file, use an Excel format library.